# Call method from custom class without creating new instance, IntegerLiterallConvertible error with Int argument

Tags: ios, class, swift, methods

I'm trying to call a class method without creating a new instance.  I'm pretty sure the method call is correct.  I created a class called CalculateWeek.  This class has several methods which do operations on dates. Here is my CalculateWeek class `

```
    import Foundation
    class CalculateWeek {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    var date = NSDate()

    func weekStart(weekDaySelected:Int)->NSDate?{
        //Get Current Weekday
        let currentWeekday = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate:date)
        var weekDay = [currentWeekday.weekday]  //date component
        println("Current weekday is \(weekDay[0])") //

        var daysToSubtract = 1
        let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = daysToSubtract

        let startDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: todayStart!, options: nil)  
        return startDate  
    }
```

Then I try to call this method from my View Controller Class :

```
var tempWeekEnd = CalculateWeek.weekStart(1)
```

And I get the error "Type CalculateWeek' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
I know the code is correct because if I copy and paste the method weekStart into my View Controller class it works fine.  It must have something to do with how I am calling the method, but I can't figure it out.  In the method my argument type is Int, and I'm sending an Int.

Comment: You can make the method a Type method by putting the word "class" in front of func, and moving calendar and date inside the method. That might work, but it depends on what todayStart is. Where does that come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not creating an object once (private attribute maybe) & using it after? Without creating any instance is impossible, `var tempWeekEnd = CalculateWeek().weekStart(1)` worked, so you need to create one instance.

```
private var cw = CalculateWeek()
...
var tempWeekEnd = cw.weekStart(1)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I see couple of problem in the code:

1. The weekStart() method is not a class method, so it can not be called the way you want to call. You need instance to call it.
2. The date you are manipulating is a instance member that will not be accessible from weekStart() if you make it class method.

I advice either you call weekStart() on a created instance of CalculateWeek or make it class method to call the way you want.

On a related note I request you check out my framework for date manipulation [here](https://github.com/abdullah-chhatra/iDate). It has quite a bit of wrappers you may want.